# Why is javascript array being populate with key values

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, array-push

I have an empty array that I would like to populate with values that I am getting from a loop like:

```js
var testArray = [];
var data = [
    {values:[3,4,3,4]},
    {values:[3434]},
    {values:[3,43,4]}
];

for ( i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
    amounts = data[i].values.length;
    console.log(amounts);
    testArray.push(amounts);
}
console.log(testArray);
```

When I `console.log()` the 'amounts' variable, I get a list of all of my integers, but if I `console.log()` the 'testArray' variable, I get an array of key values, such as testArray = [ 0:126, etc ].

Why is my array not just populated with the amounts?

Comment: Array does have numerical indices right ?

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle..

Comment: Yes, but I would like my array to look like...[124, 201, 104, 103].  Why aren't the 'amounts' just populating the array?

Comment: Here is working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w9k9dy4e/ . Not sure how your data object looks like.

Comment: Can you show the `data` array? cuz when I made one, it is working

Comment: @JordanBarber — `console` has its own way of representing things, `console.log(JSON.stringify(testArray))` should show you expected result :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're storing the `length` of each `values` into `amounts` and then push that `amounts` into the `testArray` so the result will be an array of lengths not values. If you try to push the `values` directly you'll end up with a two dimensional array, what you should do is to use [**concat**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) like this:

```js
var testArray = [];
var data = [
    {values:[3,4,3,4]},
    {values:[3434]},
    {values:[3,43,4]}
];

for ( i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
    amounts = data[i].values; // amounts should be the values array not its length
  
    testArray = testArray.concat(amounts); // concat testArray with the current values array and store it back into testArray to continue accumulatig the result
}

console.log(testArray);
```